# Computer automatically switches on in the morning

Tags: boot, bios, log

I have a small but annoying problem. For a while my computer has been switching on randomly in the morning around 3:45 AM or so. I have no idea how to fix this, i have checked a lot in the system configurations in the BIOS and everything is good. Here are some log file I found when the computer boots up in the morning.

```
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="1031" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset

Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu

Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct

Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.13.0-37-generic (buildd@kapok) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 (Ubuntu 3.13.0-37.64-generic 3.13.11.7)

Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic root=UUID=e81b49dd-5afe-4509-9ec8-0895651a4f21 ro profile
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Mar 19 03:45:40 hazza-Satellite-S70t-B kernel: [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
```

I really hope you can solve it! If you need any more logs just say so.

Sorry for the late update, but I have tried to go and look for the BIOS timer but I cannot seem to find it anywhere, my laptop is a Toshiba Satellite, has anybody else had a problem like this?

Comment: Wake-on-lan perhaps? Just an ideea...

Comment: The only things that can "wake up" a system are: A physical switch (including one in the socket), a BIOS timer or RTC, a DSP during suspension (you did not mention whether the system is suspended or hibernated of "plain off") Specially crafted Wake-on-LAN magic packets (can come from another machine on the LAN or even the Internet depending on your router) or a short circuit in the electrical subsystem or even a power surge!
A lot of the "answers" below are uninformed, so please [edit] your question and add what you've tried and/or measured already and what the exact state of the system is...

Comment: Well I think the power surge/short circuit can be ruled out because it specifically wakes up at an exact time.

Answer (score 2):

Check your BIOS, maybe it is set like that (Timer) or Wake-On-LAN or something of that sort. Just reset BIOS Settings and Done!

Comment: nope, i also switched it off and checked multiple times, but thx for trying.